# Swift generic operator

Tags: generics, swift, operator-overloading

I wrote a class like this one:

```
struct Size {
    var width:Double=0
    var height:Double=0
    init(width:Double=0,height:Double=0)
    {
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
    }
    [...]
}
```

Now i want the ability to divide a Size for a certain number, and i would like to use generics to get the function for each type convertible to Double. For example **Int**, **CGFloat**, **Float**

But when i insert the function:

```
func /<T>(lhs:Size,rhs:T)->Size
{
    return Size(width:lhs.width/Double(rhs),height:lhs.height/Double(rhs))
}
```

I get the error

```
error: cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(width: Double, height: Double)'
        return Size(width:Double(lhs.width/rhs),height:Double(lhs.height/rhs))
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

That is really weird because the list passed is of the exact types defined in the class (Double)..

If i rewrite it in this way:

```
func /<T>(lhs:Size,rhs:T)->Size
{
    let drhs=Double(rhs)
    return Size(width:lhs.width/drhs,height:lhs.height/drhs)
}
```

then i get the error:

```
error: cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'T'
    let drhs=Double(rhs)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

which is even weirder because the Swift library file has got a lot of initializers for Double, from Int, or Float types:

```
extension Double {
    init(_ v: UInt8)
    init(_ v: Int8)
    init(_ v: UInt16)
    init(_ v: Int16)
    init(_ v: UInt32)
    init(_ v: Int32)
    init(_ v: UInt64)
    init(_ v: Int64)
    init(_ v: UInt)
    init(_ v: Int)
}

extension Double {
    init(_ v: Float)
    init(_ v: Float80)
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I think the real error is can't find function `/ (Double, T)`. also  divide operator only support `/ (Double, Double)` unless you provide more overloads.

Comment: I edited a bit the question, clarifying some parts. I understand that the division of Double by a generic T is not defined, but that should give an error only when i bind a type to T which is not Double nor convertible to Double, for example String. But why the error when i didn't even called the function?

Comment: Swift generic is very different to C++ template. The type constraint tell the compiler all the things you can do on the type. this is case, it have no constraint, which means you can't do much with it.

Answer (score 5):

In swift generics require type safety which done by constraining it through protocols. This is a much better than in C++ where safety cannot be assumed with generics. Usually, you can use protocols from the Standard Library to implement these generics but unfortunately in your case you will need to define a special protocol and extend all the types that you want to be able to use. I've done it for Int and Float but you can do the same thing with all types you want to use.

```
protocol DoubleConvertible
{
    func toDouble() -> Double
}
extension Int : DoubleConvertible
{
    func toDouble() -> Double
    {
        return Double(self)
    }
}
extension Float: DoubleConvertible
{
    func toDouble() -> Double
    {
        return Double(self)
    }
}
func /<T : DoubleConvertible>(lhs: Size, rhs: T) -> Size
{
    return Size(width: lhs.width / rhs.toDouble(), height: lhs.height / rhs.toDouble())
}
```

The reason you have to do it manually is because none of the standard library protocols (that I know of) define a requirement such that numbers can be converted to a Double.

Comment: thanks, i'll try this and accept the answer if it works (I think it should)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `rhs` is a generic type and you can't divide a double by a generic type.
Something like this works :

```
func / (lhs:Size,rhs:Double)->Size
{
    return Size(width: lhs.width/rhs, height:lhs.height/rhs)
}
```

Comment: that would certainly work for dividing by double, but i want to also divide for every type convertible to double, for example Int. I'll try to edit and clarify my question.

Comment: Also i don't get why "you can't divide a double by a generic type".. A generic acts as the type it is called with, so if i call the function with the rhs argument being a Double, it can definitely make the division..